# Copying output of the code into a word document

Tags: r, ms-word, formatting, sink

Is there a proper way/a command to copy the output of R and paste it in a Word document, without loosing the formatting?
I already tried to put the next command at the beginning of my syntax:

```
sink("./output.txt", append = T) #write output to file output.txt
```

And I wrote the next command at the end of my syntax:

```
sink()   #stop recording
```

It gives me a text file (in R) with the results of my output, but when I paste it in a Microsoft Word document, I still loose the formatting.

Comment: If you're familiar with R Markdown, the most straightforward way would be to have your workflow in R so you can easily create the report with tables embedded in one document. Barring that, you could have an R Markdown file output a word document and copy and paste the table from that. https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/word-document.html

Comment: Package `DescTools` has functions to write R output to Word or Powerpoint documents.

Comment: @dcarlson could you prove an example? I can't find an easy to use function in the package

Comment: I can't provide an example because I don't have a licensed copy of Microsoft Office which is required by `DescTools`. The manual page for the Powerpoint interface, including examples is at [DescTools](https://cran.r-project.org/web//packages/DescTools/DescTools.pdf) beginning on page 444 which includes examples. I do not think that R Markdown requires a licensed copy of Microsoft Office (page 23) so that is the better approach if you do not have the software.

Answer (score 0):

Use the docket package to output R data to Word documents. Add flags to the document where you want R data to be inserted (E.G: «Author», «Date», «Calculation»), then use getDictionary("/path/to/file") to create a dictionary of flags and their replacement values. Call docket(template_path, dictionary, output_path) to create a copy of the Word document with the data populated in.

The formatting of the original flags is preserved so the replacement values will have the same size/font/bolding/color/highlighting/etc as the original file.

**Pseudocode:**

```
document_path <- "C:/User/path/to/document.docx" #document with flags added
myDictionary <- getDictionary(document_path) #Dictionary of flags found
View(myDictionary) 

##Populate dictionary
myDictionary[1,2] <- "John Doe" #Assume flag 1 is "«Author»"
myDictionary[2,2] <- Sys.Date() #Assume flag 2 is "«Date»"
myDictionary[3:10,2] <- df$value #Assume flags 3-10 should be replaced with data from an R dataframe
myDictionary[11,2] <- sum(df$value) #Assume flag 11 should be the sum of this dataframe

checkDictionary(myDictionary) #Ensure dictionary is valid
View(myDictionary) #Visually inspect dictionary

##Create copy of document with populated data
output_path <- "C:/User/path/to/output.docx"
docket(document_path, myDictionary, output_path)

##Alternatively, to overwrite the original document
docket(document_path, myDictionary, document_path)
```

Guide: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/docket/vignettes/docket_guide.html

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2KVcgnf0MI&ab_channel=ProgrammingwithIan

**Note)**

1. Currently, docket only works with .doc/.docx files
2. Errors may occur if original document does not have UTF-8 encoding ([guide to convert document to UTF-8 in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choose-text-encoding-when-you-open-and-save-files-60d59c21-88b5-4006-831c-d536d42fd861#:%7E:text=1%20Click%20the%20File%20tab.%202%20Click%20Options.,select%20the%20encoding%20standard%20that%20%2E%2E%2E%20See%20More))
3. Cannot have a non-basic Latin character directly proceeding a flag. Must be inserted in R. Example:

> - **No:** €«Price» <- "399"
> - **Yes:** «Price» <- "€399"